# how to implement the code in service layer

Tags: service

[image]

where to do the code for dynamic SOQL , error handling, fail-over intimate mechanism, log mechanism in this apex service layer
pls advise

Comment: Hi All,  In the above diagram ,Can I call SOQL in a service layer itself ? or i should use only selector layer to achive SOQL,  how to display the captured error message on a page based on language please advise.

Answer (score 2):

Adding my two cents here. A service class is expected to be a stateless class having service methods, each representing a single unit of functionality. So, each method should be a composite unit and should throw appropriate errors in case of any failures.

Exception handling should be done within Service methods classes too, to handle exceptions appropriately. This is majorly used for internal purposes and notifying error details to other layers.

From user level perspective, exception handling should always be done at the public level endpoint for e.g. VF page button click handlers, action methods, web service, triggers (appropriate considerations required) etc. So that, irrespective of any error thrown by any underlying layer, public layer always catches it and handles it appropriately (log the error OR display appropriate error message to user etc.)

You can find more details in this blog:-  https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Enterprise_Patterns_-_Service_Layer

Answer (score 0):

You must write dynamic SOQL in Apex Service Class's `Process` method. If anything wrong happens you can return to visualforce page with the error message otherwise on detail page. This service class method will be called from Controller/Extension method.

Same thing is shown in image as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider MVC (Model-View-Controller) model,

**Model** - It will have logic to perform database operations (data changes). For your case it is service class. So dynamic SOQL should reside in service class.

**View** (visualforce page) - View represents the visualization of the data .

**Controller** (Standard/custom controller,controller extensions) - It controls the data flow into model and updates the view whenever data changes. It keeps view and model separate. You call process method of service class from controller.

Error handling needs to be done in each and every apex class. If exception occurs in service class or controller, you can write a code in controller to redirect to visualforce page with proper error message.